# How to determine largest of three user input numbers with "determine highest number" and "reset" button

Tags: javascript, onclick

This is the HTML part of it. I am super new to javascript and my current notes arent too helpful. I have declared my three numbers so far, next is determining the if/if else statements and getting the buttons to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <title>Highest Number</title>
    <script src="clientCode/Lab4PartBScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action=#>
        <h2>Determine Highest Number</h2>
        <p>
            Enter three numbers:<br />
            1. <input type="text" id="txtFirst" /><br />
            2. <input type="text" id="txtSecond" /><br />
            3. <input type="text" id="txtThird" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Highest Number:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="txtHighest" /><br />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Determine Highest Number" id="btnDetermine" onclick="btnDetermine_onclick()" />
            <input type="reset" />    
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! You can first begin with trying to get the values of your textfields, try to display them with console.log(), alert() or check their values with debug mode. Then, you can write the if/else statements, and display the result. Same goes for button onClick action. EDIT: I assumed you hadn't written any JavaScript code yet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you include the JavaScript code in this question? it will allow users to better answer your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

After getting the three numbers from your HTML, you might use Math.max() function.
Example:

```
let num1 = 3, num2 = 5, num3 = 1;
let higherNumber = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
```

Also I recommend you to take a look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max and visit MDN's documentation to improve your knowledge of Javascript and as future reference. Also take a look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps to setup your Javascript if you need further help on it.

Comment: In English: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max ;)